# Test development is not working on Shopify app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

i am trying to test my Annual plan setup on my shopify app using graphQl but test development is not working
any help would be appreciated
**code**
[image]

Thank you

Comment: For testing purposes you can include "test": true when creating the charge. This prevents the credit card from being charged. Test shops and demo shops can't be charged.

Comment: Yes i pass test variables “test”=true

Comment: Can you please help me with this test stuff in GrapgQl ?

Comment: @SapnaDorbi this is my Shopify store -> https://apps.shopify.com/announcement-bar-with-slider

Comment: You need to pass "test" true in your query. like this -  
$query = Query::mutation();
 $query->field('appSubscriptionCreate')
->attribute( 'name','annual')
 ->attribute('test',true)
 ->attribute('returnUrl',$returnUrl)
  $query->build();

Comment: Yes i pass it and it’s already working fine in monthly recurring charges but it’s not working on annual recu..charges

Comment: Hey @SapnaDorbi, Please check this updated question i attach code image.. is it okay ?

Comment: @Dakopatel.. please share the code you've set up, not the screenshot. Looks like you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Dakopatel, update your gQuery,  "test" variable is missing in it.

Comment: okay i will try thank you

Comment: @SapnaDorbi it's working fine Thank you Very much ! :)

Comment: @Dakopatel You're welcome! Keep Learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mutation is wrong. You're passing a variable but not defining it. Please follow Shopify docs here -

Change gQuery to below

```
mutation appSubscriptionCreate($name: String!, $lineItems: [AppSubscriptionLineItemInput!]!, $returnUrl: URL!, $test: Boolean, $trialDays: Int) {
  appSubscriptionCreate(name: $name, lineItems: $lineItems, returnUrl: $returnUrl, test: $test, trialDays: $trialDays) {
    appSubscription {
      id
    }
    confirmationUrl
    userErrors {
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's working fine Thank you ! 
now Trail_days is not working  can you please help me ?

Comment: If it helped you please upvote and mark it as answer. Also, there's nothing called as "Trail_days"; check your syntax.